# REST API including/filtering additional fields/resources/collections

Tags: rest, zend-framework

I'm developing a REST API using Zend Framework 1.12.3. It would be useful having a param to be able to return additional information to be returned (other collections/resources or parent/child resources).

E.g. http://api.example.com/project/:id?include=Company,Company.users

where Company, Company.users represent the company to which the project is assigned to and the users of that company, and therefore these two collections are included in the response that otherwise wouldn't have been included.

I've read briefly about this (Limiting which fields are returned by the API here http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#limiting-fields), but I would like to know more.

Are there any guidelines for best practices regarding this issue? Do you have any example regrading this?

Have you ever faced a similar issue (including fields, filtering fields, etc), and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Some examples of syntax used for field expansion/field selection in the wild:

- Facebook's [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/). I quite like the syntax  here that allows pagination of sub resources.
- LinkedIn's [field selectors](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/field-selectors)

We wanted to provide similar functionality on our APIs, and have gone with similar syntax to the Facebook field expansion. Unfortunately there is not much in the way of of libraries to help with this, so we have been rolling our own implementation. (There is [yoga](https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga) for Java, and [shona](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c0d0ece4b0ed877035680e/chapter0/about) for scala is in early stages, but neither of those help you with PHP).